# Weird string result when creating a basic cipher in c++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a simple cipher and i got stuck on a weird problem with which i believe is with my IF's.

```
    char name[25];
    char cipher[25];
    gets(name);

    int i;
    for( i = 0; i <= 25; i++ )
     {
         cipher[i] = name[i];
         if( name[i] = 'g' ) {
            cipher[i] = 'a';
         };
         cout << cipher[i];
     };
```

`cipher[i] = name[i];` is there to copy one array to another, so then only one array gets changed. It works. And rest of the program, in my understanding, works like this: if there is a letter `g` in `name[0]`, make it a letter `a` in `cipher[0]` and if there isn't, just skip, repeat 25 times. But the results are so random to me i don't understand what's going on at all...

[image: img]

Comment: Assignment (`=`) is not equality (`==`)

Comment: Probably not related to your error, but `i <= 25;` will loop one too many times.

Comment: Outside of the typo, please [don't use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). It's so dangerous that it was removed completely in modern C++.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen well, in my school we don't learn anything modern so that's alright i guess! teacher made us use this method... for real though i'll make sure to not use it in any serious program!

Comment: @scohe001 ah, didn't notice that, thank you!

Comment: @crashmstr it works... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement, you're doing an assignment rather than comparison:

`if( name[i] = 'g' )` should have `==` like so: `if( name[i] == 'g' )`

Comment: Honestly i don't know how to react to that now. I've tried it before and it didn't work, i was brute forcing anything that came to my mind, and now it just started to work... thank you!